# Creating single knex connection pool for all tests in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, jestjs, knex.js

I use `knex` in my project and I try to write tests with it (with `jest`). I want to execute some scripts before each test and after each test, so each test will run on the same data in db.

I tried to create a global connection pool with knex, and execute the scripts in the tests setup. The problem is when I have tests in different `describe` scope.

For example, lets say I have 2 tests, each test is in different `describe` scope

```
import { connection } from './global-setup.ts'
describe('first', () => {
    beforeEach( async () => {
        await connection.raw(...)
    }
    afterEach( async () => {
        await connection.raw(...)
    }
    it('test1', () => {...})
}
```

and same for the second test. The result is that the scripts in beforeEach is not always run, And as a result the second tests sometimes pass, and sometimes fail.

I did noticed that the connection pool is initalized every time for different describe scope, which I think is the cause of the problem. (and if I put the first and the second test in the same describe scope they always pass)

How can I fix this? or how can I make one connection pool for all the describe tests?

Comment: You are missing `await` from your raw queries.

Comment: @MikaelLepistö updated my question, it is not relevant to the problem

Comment: Would be good if you are able to show some actual failing code. Though from your description I would suspect that since Jest runs all the tests parallel your beforeEach / afterEach are messing with the same data, so your test cases in different describes doesn't have stable data to work with.